# GtkComboBox related qusestion

Tags: c, gtk

How to set GtkComboBox default selectio?
How to Adjust X, Y location of Drop Down menu of GtkComboBox?
I want to display Drop Down menu at the lower edge of GtkComoBox.

Also I want to set text color of Selected text in combo box to white.

Thank,
PP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk_combo_box_set_active` is the function to use to set the default selection.

Here's an example:

```
gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), index);
```

Where index is an integer value which corresponds to the index number of the item you want as a default. What this value is will be entirely dependent on the data within the GtkTreeModel you have the combo box using.

As for your other questions, I don't know, I suggest you install dev-help, or scour the GTK documentation at the GTK website.